# Find direction to hit moving target (Firing bullet at moving target)

Tags: c#, math, trigonometry, algebra

I've read through several other solutions here on stackexchange and not find a straight forward solution for this problem.

I've have a **sourcePoint** and **targetPoint**. The target has a **targetVelocity** (speed and direction), and source has **sourceSpeed**.

I need a way to calculate **sourceDirection** (which becomes **sourceVelocity** using **sourceSpeed**)

I've been looking at the math and it must be some kind of equation where the function may sometime return false, ie. the bullet can't catch up to the target, depending on **targetVelocity** and **sourceSpeed**

My current solution gives a direction but doesn't take into account the additional length required to reach the target as it's based on the length to target at firing time.

Also, if I can avoid Sqrt/Normalize that would be great for performance, but I'm looking for fairly simple/elegant solution.

```
    /// Returns sourceVelocity
    public static Vector2 calcBullet(Vector2 source, float sourceSpeed, Vector2 target, Vector2 targetVelocity)
    {
        var diff = target - source;
        var dist = Vector2.Distance(diff, Vector2.Zero);
        diff += targetVelocity * (dist / sourceSpeed);
        diff.Normalize();
        return diff * sourceSpeed;
    }
```

Comment: it's a simple linear equation - your target travels on a line (just introduce time as the variable) and so does your source - now you just have to set up two linear equations like `sourcePoint = sourceOrigin + t * sourceVelo` and `targetPoint = targetOrigin + t * targetVelo` and then set them both equal - in the end (if you look at this component-wise) you'll get 2 linear equations having 3 variables (`sourceVelo_x`, `sourceVelo_y` and `t`) and you *just* have to solve them (it should be really simple school math)

Comment: btw: I just saw that you'll want to keep your speed constant - so you can express one of the `sourceVelo_?` parts by the other (this will involve sqrts) - but still you should be able to solve this with school math - only now you'll get a quadratic formula and can continue with the famous [quadratic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation) - please at least try it for yourself and say where your trouble is ;)

Comment: I don't think it's as simple as you make it sound tho, I'm looking for a firing direction, and that could potentially be a non-possible solution aswell. I could always make a testing function and with say 10 iterations that binary searches itself to a decent solution, but that is both ugly and costly

Comment: For an accurate impact prediction between a constant velocity source (bullet) and constant velocity target, you have to suffer two square root calcs (but it's just once per bullet, not once per frame so perf isn't really that affected). One in the quadratic equation and one to determine the time to impact (via the distance calc). Here's how I implemented the quadratic equation: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/25292/1923

Comment: but it is - the non -solution will just be the determinant being negative ... take a sheet of paper and try it

Comment: Thanks for that Steve H! Your implementation worked great for me, you should have posted the code snippet as an answer to the question as it provided C# code.

Comment: @jsmars thanks, but by the time I thought of redoing it, Douglas had posted and essentially is the same answer.

Comment: In the question Steve H answered, there was the additional assumption that the bullet moved faster than the target. You have to be careful that there might or might not be a solution if the bullet is slower than the target, so Steve H's code there (for example, the line `float q = (float)Math.Sqrt((b * b) - 4 * a * c) / (2 * a);`) may have to be modified or wrapped in some try-catch block to handle division by 0 and square roots of negative numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the sourceSpeed is greater than the targetSpeed (magnitude of the targetVelocity), then there is always at least one solution. If the sourceSpeed is smaller or equal to the targetSpeed, there might or might not be any solutions.

You can parametrize the path of the target by the amount of time that it takes for the target to get there, t. You want to solve an equation (which turns out to be quadratic) for the equality between the time it takes for the bullet to get there (distance(t)/sourceSpeed) and the time it takes for the target to arrive, t, and only solutions for nonnegative t will work.

```
distance(t) = magnitude(target + t*targetVelocity - source) 
            = sqrt((target.x-source.x + t*targetVelocity.x)^2 + (target.y-source.y + t*targetVelocity.y)^2)
            = sqrt(quadratic(t))
```

So, you want to solve

```
t = sqrt(quadratic(t))/sourceSpeed
t* sourceSpeed = sqrt(quadratic(t))
t^2 * sourceSpeed^2 = quadratic(t)
```

If the t^2 terms cancel (which happens when the target speed equals the source speed), you get a linear equation (which would give you a division by 0 if you tried to use the quadratic formula). Otherwise, you get a quadratic equation you can solve using the quadratic formula, although you should check whether the discriminant b^2-4ac is negative before trying to take the square root. If the discriminant is negative, there are no solutions. Only nonnegative real solutions give you a way to shoot the target.

If there are two positive real solutions, you have to pick one. Once you find the correct value of t, t_solution, you know where the target will be, (target + t_solution * targetVelocity), and you can aim in that direction from the source.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for, the math is still a bit difficult but with help of Steve H link on the original question I was able to get it working correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the amount of time you want it to take to reach the target.  Try these two formulas

```css
bullet distance = target distance + (target velocity * time)

bullet velocity * time = target distance + (target velocity * time)​
```

Comment: But he doesn't know the time to reach target and can not arbitrarily set it if he wants the speed of the bullet to be constant.

Comment: The time can be computer by knowing the other variables.  The bullet speed must be greater than the target velocity otherwise you never reach the target.  So you must choose a bullet speed that will solve the equation.   There isn't a single solution since the bullet velocity can vary.  So the answer really lies along a straight line (bullet velocity vs. time).

Comment: It's quite possible to hit the target with a bullet speed that is smaller than the target speed. In this question, the bullet speed is fixed, but the direction is not. You have to choose the direction in which you fire the constant-speed bullet. If you are adjusting the bullet velocity, you are solving a different problem, not the one asked here.